# Adding TextFlow to FXML controller makes GUI blank

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

So I made a basic application which normally looks like...

[image]

But if I add a reference to the FXML TextFlow component (fx:id="tofl") in the controller class, the GUI goes blank like...

[image]

Please explain why this is happening. My code is as follows:

main.FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow?>

<fx:root prefHeight="389.0" prefWidth="732.0" styleClass="grey" stylesheets="@CSS.css" type="AnchorPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
<TextFlow fx:id="tofl" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="299.0" prefWidth="703.0" />
<Button fx:id="addBtn" layoutX="596.0" layoutY="320.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add new Text block" />
<TextField fx:id="txt" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="320.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="572.0" />
<CheckBox fx:id="italic" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="360.0" mnemonicParsing="false" styleClass="chckbox" text="Italic" />
<CheckBox fx:id="bold" layoutX="104.0" layoutY="360.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Bold" />
<CheckBox fx:id="underline" layoutX="180.0" layoutY="360.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Underline" />
<ChoiceBox fx:id="color" layoutX="270.0" layoutY="356.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="121.0" />
<ChoiceBox fx:id="size" layoutX="399.0" layoutY="356.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="121.0" />
</fx:root>
```

mainController.java

```
package textflow;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class mainController extends AnchorPane {

    @FXML TextFlow tofl; //Problem here. If this line exists, the GUI is blank white. If I remove it, the GUI shows up. The program doesn't throw ANY errors, so it might just be a bug (either in NetBeans, or my head)
    @FXML TextField txt;
    @FXML Button addBtn;
    @FXML CheckBox italic;
    @FXML CheckBox bold;
    @FXML CheckBox underline;
    @FXML ChoiceBox color;
    @FXML ChoiceBox size;

    public mainController() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();            
        } catch (IOException exception) {
        }
    }  

}
```

TextFlow.java - the main class

```
package textflow;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

 public class TextFlow extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        mainController customControl = new mainController();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(customControl));
        stage.setTitle("Custom Control");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

The "@FXML TextFlow tofl;" in mainController.java is what is causing problems. I remove it, everything is fine. I add it, it's blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the imports in `mainController.java`:

They don't contain an import for `javafx.scene.text.TextFlow` and `textflow.TextFlow` is used instead. You need to add an import to `javafx.scene.text.TextFlow`. In addition consider renaming your `TextFlow` class. Using the same type names as types in the API you use can easily lead to confusion.

When `mainController`'s constructor is executed the fxml file is handled until `FXMLLoader` tries to inject the `javafx.scene.text.TextFlow` instance to the `tofl` field which results in a `IOException` because of the mismatched types.

Since you're simply ignoring the exception in the `catch` clause instead of handling it, the constructor completes normally and the partially loaded node is added to your scene. It's usually better to at least print the exception, unless you know the exception won't cause (or indicate) an issue, since this makes debugging much easier.